# Encoding / for a URL

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib

I'm trying to encode a `/` for a URL using [urllib.quote](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote). Following the documentation I'm passing an empty string for the second parameter to ensure `/` is not excluded from being encoded:

```
print(quote('prøve med / i den', ''))
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> File "/path/to/my/file.py", line 388, in my_function
>
> print(quote('prøve med / i den', ''))
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1298, in quote
>
> return ''.join(map(quoter, s))
>
> KeyError: u'\xf8'

Comment: The error is related to the Danish character, not to the slash. Try to reduce this to a [mre].

Comment: @tripleee This is a minimal example. I need to use Norwegian characters as well as a `/`. Do I need to use a different function perhaps?

Comment: Don't ask about the slash if the slash is not the problematic character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a unicode string:

```
u'prøve med / i den'
```

Instead of:

```
'prøve med / i den'
```

---

> KeyError: u'\xf8'

It is the hex code for `ø`.